# Having trouble removing default admin user 'realm-admin'

Tags: realm

just installed the newest version 2.1.17 of Realm Object Server. Got it running on the IP I want it, got Realm Studio working and running, but no matter what config I set on the server, the default admin 'realm-admin' user always comes back after deleting it (this is after I restart my pm2 instance).

Also, can't seem to figure out how to give it a new password if deleting the user permanently is not an option. Because right now it's just open to the world.  I don't want those values to go back to default when pm2 is restarted or the box is rebooted.  Any help out there with this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to keep the realm-admin user (or some other user with admin privilege) if you want to administer your Realm Object Server.

Changing password should fairly straight forward:
1. Connect to ROS
2. Go to the "Users" tab
3. Select the "realm-admin" user
4. Click the "Change password" button.

[image: Changing the "realm-admin" users password]

Comment: @Torrey did that answer your question?